# Asp column chart, how can I have the tick marks on the left of the columns instead of centered?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, charts

I've spent hours trying to solve this silly problem. I create an histogram with asp chart control. All I want to do is have the xaxis label on the left of the column instead of centered on it. Xaxis lable doesn't seem to have a position property like series do, so I can't figure it out and it's frustrating.

Here's a sample code of to show you what I get approximately:

```
        private void Graphique()
    {
        // Creating the series 
        Series series2 = new Series("Series2");

        // Setting the Chart Types
        series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

        // Adding some points
        series2.Points.AddXY(1492, 12);
        series2.Points.AddXY(2984, 0);
        series2.Points.AddXY(4476, 1);
        series2.Points.AddXY(5968, 2);
        series2.Points.AddXY(7460, 2);
        series2.Points.AddXY(8952, 12);
        series2.Points.AddXY(10444, 4);
        series2.Points.AddXY(11936, 3);
        series2.Points.AddXY(13428, 3);
        series2.Points.AddXY(14920, 5);
        series2.Points.AddXY(16412, 1);

        Chart3.Series.Add(series2);

        Chart3.Width = 600;
        Chart3.Height = 600;

        // Series visual
        series2.YValueMembers = "Frequency";
        series2.XValueMember = "RoundedValue";
        series2.BorderWidth = 1;
        series2.ShadowOffset = 0;
        series2.IsXValueIndexed = true;

        // Setting the X Axis
        Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;
        Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = Double.NaN;
        Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "kbps";

        // Setting the Y Axis
        Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = 2;
        Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = Double.NaN;
        Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Frequency";
    }
```

Now my real chart looks like this, [image: Actual result]

I would like something similar to this website :
[Desired layout chart](http://www.infragistics.com/samples/aspnet/chart/histogram-chart)

You see, the x label is on the left, which makes way more sense considering that each column of an histogram represents the frequency of a range of values.....

Any help would be appreciated...